# Docker-compose: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: docker, docker-compose

If I launch a Docker container by first creating the image and then running it (`docker build --rm -t myApp` + `docker run -p 80:80 -P -d myApp`), everything works fine.

But, when I do the same with Docker-compose and access to localhost, the browser returns me a ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error (not the typical: "Connection refused").

Where am I wrong?

Docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
 myApp:
  build: myApp
  ports:
   - "80:8000"
```

/myApp/Dockerfile:

```
FROM fedora-nodeJS
ADD app.js /
EXPOSE 8000
CMD node app
```

/myApp/app.js:

```
var http  = require('http');

var PORT  = 8000;
var ADDR  = '0.0.0.0';

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(301, { Location: 'http://stackoverflow.com' });
    res.end();
}).listen(PORT,ADDR);
```

*:: I know it makes no sense at all launch just one container with Docker-compose, but I had the same ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error when trying to launch several containers, so I ended up with this ridiculous scenario trying to understand whats failing.*

Answer (score 5):

In the command ,I can see

```
docker run -p 80:80 -P -d myApp
```

that you are exposing internal port 80 ,but in

> docker-compose.yml

you are exposing internal port 8000

```
ports:
   - "80:8000"
```

Is that a typo ?
Which port you actually want to expose for your app?

Answer (score 2):

As @emme pointed out, it is probably a typo in your case.

For anyone having the same problem but are 100% positive that their port configuration is correct, it might be a problem with your antivirus.
My company had ESET endpoint Antivirus installed on my mac and by default the antivirus blocks access to `localhost:80`. While the server can be bound to port 80, no client connection to this server would work while the "Enable HTTP checking" (under "Web access protection") is activated.

Sounds like a stupid answer but I lost an afternoon figuring out why `docker run -p 80:80 -P -d myApp` would not work while `docker run -p 81:80 -P -d myApp` would.